# Website's image does't show when link is shared

Tags: html, facebook, image, share

I used [facebook linter](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) to debug my website.

It's everything ok, icluding the image (og:image ...)

However, when I share the link on facebook, there is no image.

Everyone knows why or how to solve this?

The site is [oddvise.com](http://oddvise.com)

Thanks,
Joao

Comment: It works! Here is the screenshot : http://i.imgur.com/N5XwHOs.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a Facebook problem. wait a day or two, and you will see in your next shares that it will appear.

Adding to that, `http://www.oddvise.com/` does not exist. so whenever you share, you need to use `http://oddvise.com/` instead of `http://www.oddvise.com/`

Comment: This guy's answer is absolutely correct. You are doing redirection wrong. You have to make 301 header redirection not JavaScript redirection.